# Can't Update Partial View With Ajax ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to update my partial View with Ajax, but for some reason, it doesn't work. If I use load method (and comment ajax code), it works. this is my code:

this is my main View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplicationMVC.Models.Test>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Testing";
}

<div id="partial">
@await Html.PartialAsync("Question", Model.ToList()[0])
</div>

<input type="button" id="b" value="next" class="btn btn-default" />

<script>

$("#b").click(function () {

    //this code doesn't work

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Test/Question',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: '@Model.ToList()[1].ID' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partial").html(result);
        }
    });

    //this code works
    @*$("#partial").load('@Url.Action("Question","Test",new { id=Model.ToList()[1].ID })');*@

});
```

this is my question action method int **Test** controller:

```
public IActionResult Question(int id)
{
    return View(Methods.GetTestById(id));
}
```

what mistake do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `dataType: "json",` but your method returns a view (html), not  `JsonResult` so an exception is being thrown.

Either omit the `dataType` option (the function will work it out based on the response) or change it to `dataType: 'html'`

In addition, your can delete the `contentType` option. You are making a GET which has no body so its ignored (and if it was a POST, your method would also fail because you have not stringified the data).

Your url should also be `/Test/Question` (leading forward slash), and you should always use the `@Url.Action()` method to generate the url

Your function should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Question","Test")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: '@Model.ToList()[1].ID' },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#partial").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to add, that there is no exception thrown when I click the button

Comment: Of course an exception is being thrown (you would be getting a `500(Internal Server Error)` - note also the edit regarding the url

Comment: You should learn to use your browser tools to debug your code :) - the incorrect url would be giving a `404` error, and the `dataType` would be giving a `500` error