# Load partial view through controller on Search button click

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC app using razor. I have searchQuery.cshtml and a (individually working perfectly) viewQuery.cshtml pages. In my searchQuery page, I let user enter queryId and on clicking "Search" button I want to run the action of ViewQuery that displays the results in viewQuery.cshtml and show the viewQuery below the search button area.

I am not good working with Ajax or so. On Search btn click, I call the viewQuery Get action thru ajax. In the button click, I pass the entered queryId of type int. But, when I load searchQuery page, it throws null exception for passing the queryId. I searched few hous, but didn't get any solution.

searchQuery.cshtml      **UPDATED**

```
<div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QueryId)
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input asp-for="QueryId" class="form-control" />
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Show" />
        <!-- CHANGE IN CALL -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ShowResult()">Search</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Query Answer</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> 

<script>
     function ShowResult() {
        // Retrieve queryId
        var queryId = $("#QueryId").val();

        // DisplayS PROPERLY
        alert("Entered ID " + queryId);

        // TRIED '/query/viewQuery' ALSO
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../query/viewQuery', 
            data: { queryId: queryId },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);    // **DISPLAYS [Object: object]**
                $("#myModalBodyDiv").html(response);

                $('#myModal').modal("show");
            }, error: function (response) {
                alert("Error: " + response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My ViewQuery action in controller    **UPDATED**

```
        [Route("[controller]/viewQuery/{queryId:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ViewQuery(int queryId)
        {
            // Retrieve Data from api using HttpClient
            ....
            return PartialView("ViewQuery", qVM); // PartialView(qVM); //View(qVM);
        }
```

Search Query Action  **UPDATED**

```
        [Route("searchQuery")]   // customer/searchQuery
        public IActionResult SearchQuery()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Can anyone please help me how do I achieve my goal. Simple - a text box were user enters queryId. A button on click, want to pass the entered queryId, call a GET action  on controller and get the response. Finally show the response below the search button. I was just trying with the above modal dialog, I prefer text and not dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try & isolate the issue.

Instead of using model.QueryId in the searchQuery.cshtml, simply hardcode any reference to "modelid" - that way at least you are eliminating the possibility that Model is null on that page. Then instead of onclick="ShowResult(@Model.QueryId)">  , hard code some known id instead of @Model.QueryId. Then debug to see if your ViewQuery  action method id hit. If the method is hit, then you can take it from there.

Also, I noticed that your jquery calls may need to be modified:

Instead of: $('myModalBodyDiv').html(response); it should probably be $('#myModalBodyDiv').html(response);  (the "#" is missing ..) - same for $('myModal').

Comment: thanks for pointing the mistake of missing '#'. Please have a look at the updated code. I can retrieve the queryId in ShowResult(). ViewQuery is hit, retrieves data thru api, and ready to return with proper value. In ajax call, in return **success**, it shows alert with [object: object] - No html code. I tried with regular div also, but no success. It's in the return of view not as html.

Comment: OK, I have tested your scenario, and whether I use View or PartialView, as expected I am getting the HTML content. You can comment out your API access code & simply try to pass the View to the AJAX code either without the model (you can create a dummy view to test) or initiate a dummy model & pass your view with the dummy model (the idea is to eliminate the API call & test). Then you should test it with a plain view without any model associated - simply to test if it works as required. The idea is to keep adding code to find out at which point it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Partial Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2)(`ViewQuery` page) , in your `searchQuery` page , you could use Ajax to call server side action with parameter ID . On server side , you can query the database with ID and return PartialView with models :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Students (StudentFilter filters)
{
     List students = Student.GetStudents(filters);
     return PartialView("_Students", students);
}
```

Then in success callback function of Ajax , you can load the html of partial view to related area in page using jQuery :

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#searchResultsGrid").html(result);
}
```

You can click [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51913.asp-net-core-mvc-how-to-load-a-partial-view.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114427/cant-update-partial-view-with-ajax-asp-net-core-mvc) for code sample if using MVC template . And [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update) is code sample if using Razor Pages .

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried as you have suggested and as per the links you shared. In alert of the view response, I see [object: object]. I have noticed that if I return Json, then ajax call receives perfectly well; but with View, just don't seem to working for me. I feel I am just little away, need to find out where ! I tried with regular div and no modal, yet same. I am using ASP.NET Core MVC Razor and all of my Views are partial only. Do I need to set any content type in Controller or ajax call to make to happen OR what could be blocking it.